React Vite deployed to Vercel But showing white page
Created a React Vite static page and it has deployed using vercel but when deployed it has white page
Repo:https://github.com/Aarif-Hussain-A-Nassar/Educa
Link:https://educa-gold.vercel.app/
Tried redeploying but still same result and also made homepage as homepage:"."
Also made homage page as vercel url but same result

https://vercel.com/docs/frameworks/vite

Missing Files Detected. rebuild the app

if does not work
change in vite.config.ts and rebuild
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  //base:"/Educa/",
  plugins: [react()],
})


Thanks Works Now when i made changes in vite.config.ts

welcome, you can give credit and vote up, close the question :)
